# How can the survival of mortal vessels decline with an increase in quality of life?

Tags: magic, gods, demons

Every 1000 years, a total solar eclipse covers the entire disk of the sun and covers the earth in its shadow. During this event, the barrier that separates the mortal world from the spiritual world weakens, allowing demons to cross over into our realm. These creatures serve Femto, an ancient being that leads a pantheon of deities known as the Godhand. Femto seeks to combine both realms into one, making him ruler of creation. As he is too powerful to cross over directly during the eclipse, he must reincarnate a portion of his power to enter it directly. This child will be immediately born to a mortal during the eclipse, allowing him to work towards bringing down the barrier permanently. Fortunately, a sect of Druidic warriors has taken it upon themselves to guard our world against this plot. This group, known as the Band of the Hawk, use a druidic spell upon the mortal vessel, preventing the birth of Femto and trapping him in the spiritual realm. Every 1000 years, a new vessel is chosen by Femto, forcing the Druids to track down the mortal and repeat the process, imprisoning Femto for another thousand years. The rise of the catholic church during the middle ages has been detrimental to the existence of pagan groups. A purge by the Inquisition has wiped out sects associated with "witchcraft", leading to the extinction of the Band. This allows Femto to proceed with his plan unheeded. However, every new vessel has died in childbirth during the eclipse, preventing Femto from being born into the mortal world and keeping him trapped in his realm.

Premature death was a constant thing in the past, as the quality of life was very low. Susceptibility to diseases, poor knowledge of medicines, and lack of access to healthcare was common for most people, reducing life expectancy. Today, however, the situation is vastly different. People can expect to live to a decent age due to an increase in the standard of living and access to life-saving medicine. Maternity death rates have dramatically decreased over time and are getting lower across the world. This should lead to Femto being able to accomplish his goal, but this has not panned out the way it should.

How can these two events be linked to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cesarian sections**

Femto isn't an easy baby to birth. Their Godhand powers make birth difficult, and they need a bit of extra time in the womb to mature. Normally, they can drive their mother to a bit of extra success in life with their mystical powers, so they can eat enough to support them even if they are a peasant.

However, in the modern world women who don't give birth at 9 months tend to get c sections. This means Femto is born prematurely, and dies upon birth due to the lack of time to mature.

Answer (score 2):

**Dare I say it?**

*Abortion*

With increasing life expectations and medicine, the choice of *when* to get kids get bigger. This choice is accompanied by a larger demand for abortion, regardless how difficult that choice is. In some countries you can even have an abortion nearly up to the moment of birth, so close that it practically is childbirth.

*Please don't make this political or religious. I do not want to add any question about the morality or whatever. Just that it happens.*

The kid could be aborted for many reasons, including birth defects. The recipient of the demon might have some strange DNA, which might lead to the decision of abortion, or a form of euthanasia to prevent senseless suffering. This last one might be chosen as the abortion didn't work.

Life is hard. So is death.

Answer (score 0):

There's been factor demonstrating exactly this in American society over the past century.  It's harder to see, because medical care has improved over the same time, but as the quality of life in America has improved, Americans have demonstrated an increasing tendency to get *fat*.

If this hadn't been offset by a reduction in mortality from disease and accident, we would have seen an actual decrease in life expectancy; as it is, I've read estimates (sorry, don't recall where, likely in second or third generation popular articles vs. original research) that this one factor, alone, has offset almost half of the life expectancy increase we might have seen from advances like antibiotics, improved surgical techniques, and better diagnostic tools.

Add to that other self-destructive habits that might come along with an increase in disposable income (recreational and addictive drugs, for instance, or general thrill-seeking) and you could easily see life expectancy actually *drop off* after a sudden increase due to a very rapid improvement in overall quality of life.

Answer (score 0):

Advances in medicine made **contraception and abortion** much safer and more effective.

If Druids can divine who is the potential mother they can use various contraception methods to prevent conception. This can be done with her permission or not. The most suitable options would probably be *pills and injections*.

If prevention is not possible, early abortion is another option. At the present time, pregnancy can be detected at very early stages: [Some very sensitive pregnancy tests can be used even before you miss a period, from as early as 8 days after conception](https://www.nhs.uk/pregnancy/trying-for-a-baby/doing-a-pregnancy-test/). If pregnancy is detected at this time, abortion will require only [medication](https://www.plannedparenthood.org/learn/abortion/the-abortion-pill).

---

Another possibility is that Femto requires an exceptional body to reincarnate. Moreover, this body drains too much of the mother's strength and resources and only exceptionally fit women that have access to the best care can survive pregnancy. Therefore, the chances of successful reincarnation are originally very small and it may never happen regardless of the advances in medicine and rising standards of living. (This also suggests that Druids never had any real role in preventing Femto from reincarnation.)